# Blender: Roll up, unroll plane without using Spiral or growing cylinder

Tags: animation, 3d, blender

We're trying to get a realistic affect of a plane being rolled up into a coil in an animation like a carpet rolling up or toilet paper being rolled onto a cardboard tube.

To two ways that are usually suggested are:

1. **Use a spiral and add a curve modifier to the plane** - but this is not an accurate representation because the first roll is the widest diameter and then the coil 'tightens'. That would not be how paper really winds onto a cardboard tube ...
2. **The Cylinder/Plane Trick** - Move a cylinder while expanding a plane (so one edge is always under the cylinder and increase, decrease the size of the cylinder. This is a clever way to mimic a ribbon being wound / unwound but out plane is actually a complex model so we wouldn't be able to get away with it.

The current animation we are working on is all in Blender Render but if Blender Cycles was the only way to crack this I would go there! ;)